# The current Shared Preferenes version does not support SliverStaggeredGrid

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I'm currently using SliverStaggeredGrid to build my appication but since it has been removed I am unable to use it not can find any other code that has replaced it. I tried using a lower version but since flutter creates certain dependencies, I was unable to use the lower version. How do I get about this:

This is the code for the SliverStaggeredGrid:

```
: SliverStaggeredGrid.countBuilder(
                        staggeredTileBuilder: (c) => const StaggeredTile.count(1, 1.5),
                        crossAxisCount: 2,
                        mainAxisSpacing: 1,
                        crossAxisSpacing: 0,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          Items model = Items.fromJson(
                              snapshot.data!.docs[index].data()!
                                  as Map<String, dynamic>);
                          return Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: ItemsDesign(
                              model: model,
                              context: context,
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                        itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                      );
```

EDIT:

Dependencies version:

```
flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  firebase_core: ^2.17.0
  firebase_auth: ^4.10.1
  cloud_firestore: ^4.9.3
  firebase_storage: ^11.2.8
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.11
  flutter_staggered_grid_view: ^0.7.0
  fluttertoast: ^8.0.8
  google_fonts: ^6.1.0
  hexcolor: ^3.0.1
  lottie: ^2.6.0
  image_picker: ^1.0.4
  geolocator: ^10.1.0
  geocoding: ^2.0.1
  intl: ^0.18.1
```

Error that is currently showing:

1. Undefined name 'SliverStaggeredGrid'.
   Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name.
2. The name 'fit' isn't a class.
   Try correcting the name to match an existing class.

Flutter Doctor results:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, 3.16.0-10.0.pre.20, on macOS 14.0 23A344 darwin-arm64, locale en-TZ)
    • Flutter version 3.16.0-10.0.pre.20 on channel master at /Users/mustafa/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision ec94ccff83 (31 hours ago), 2023-10-11 07:41:40 -0400
    • Engine revision bddb34b09c
    • Dart version 3.3.0 (build 3.3.0-6.0.dev)
    • DevTools version 2.28.1

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.1)
    • Android SDK at /Users/mustafa/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 33.0.1
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b829.9-10027231)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.0)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 15A240d
    • CocoaPods version 1.13.0

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.3)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b829.9-10027231)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.83.0)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.74.0

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • macOS (desktop) • macos  • darwin-arm64   • macOS 14.0 23A344 darwin-arm64
    • Chrome (web)    • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 117.0.5938.149
```

Comment: can you include the packages version

Comment: What error do you get when you build your app? Also post your relevant dependencies versions

Comment: I have added the package version, errors, and dependency versions as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This probably isn't an answer you want to hear, but you probably can't use SliverStaggeredGrid as-is any more.

You might have to switch to newer code from a plugin, for example [`flutter_staggered_grid_view`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view) or [`masonry_grid`](https://pub.dev/packages/masonry_grid). I believe `SliverQuiltedGridDeletate` in the flutter_staggered_grid_view package probably does what you need.

An alternative could be to copy the source code for `SliverStaggeredGrid` directly into your project or fork the plugin (assuming it's coming from a plugin) and update only what you need - as long as you can update it for the most recent flutter version it *should* work, but there's probably a good reason for it being deprecated so I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Is there anyway to convert the code I have written for SliverStaggeredGrid to SliverQuiltedGridDeletate

Comment: Definitely not anything automated, but you might be able to find something. I'd start with the docs in flutter_staggered_grid_view. Without an idea of the look you're trying to achieve and what information you already have it's hard to tell what would be the best option. You might be best off asking a new question where you just describe what you have for information and what look you're trying to achieve, but you should give it your best shot first.

Comment: I used SliverGrid.build with StaggeredGridDelegate to replace SliverQuiltedGridDeletate